# Angular form: Equivalent of constructor ngForm injection for Reactive Forms?

Tags: angular, forms, angular-reactive-forms, angular-providers

I am trying to build a component to show validation error messages like this:

```html
<form>
  <input ngModel name="firstname" required>
  <validation-error for="firstname"></validation-error> 
</form>
```

The `<validation-error>` component is amazingly simple for Template Driven forms as we can inject the `NgFrom` in the constructor and use `ngFrom.form.get(myControlName)` to find a control an its state:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'validation-error',
  template: `{{errorText}}`,
  styles: [`:host { display:block; color:red; }`]
})
export class ValidationErrorComponent  {
  @Input() for: string;  // name of input element
  constructor(
    @Optional() private ngForm: NgForm  // This works for Template forms only.
  ) { }

  get errorText() : string {
    const formControl = <FormControl>this.ngForm.form.get(this.for);
    return (formControl.errors) ? JSON.stringify(formControl.errors) : "[no error]";
  }
}
```

But the `NgForm` only seems to be injected for Template Forms. Is there an equivalent provider for Reactive Forms that gives access to the enclosing `FormGroup`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of injecting ngForm,use the ControlContainer to access FormControls.

**ControlContainer**

> A base class for directives that contain multiple registered instances of NgControl.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'validation-error',
  template: `{{errorText}}`,
  styles: [`:host { display:block; color:red; }`]
})
export class ValidationErrorComponent  {
  @Input() for: string;  // name of input element
  constructor(
     @Optional() private control: ControlContainer
  ) { }

  get errorText() : string {
    const formControl = <FormControl>(this.control as any).form.get(this.for);
    return (formControl.errors) ? JSON.stringify(formControl.errors) : "[no error]";
  }
}
```

[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-j8d39e)

Comment: ngCtrl is always null and taking off the @Optional in the constructor produces this error in the console: "NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[ValidationErrorComponent -> NgControl]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[ValidationErrorComponent -> NgControl]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for NgControl!" Do I need to to do something on the <form> to make NgControl available?

Comment: Jepp, ControlContainer did the trick!! The Example link to stackblitz.com shows exactly what I had in mind. Thanks for this!! Maybe you can also fully change the sample code above from ngCtrl NgControl to control ControlContainer for completness of the answer. I found the casting to any is not necessary.